# Run code block twice with differente variable name in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a code block in my Rails 5 app that I need to run two times, but each time with a differente variable:

```
if params[:origin]
  ride.waypoints.new(params[:origin].permit(:zip, :street, :number, :district, :city, :state))
end

if params[:destination]
  ride.waypoints.new(params[:destination].permit(:zip, :street, :number, :district, :city, :state))
end
```

As you can see it's two times exactly the same code but once i use origin and once destination. Is there an elegant way to shorten this so I don't have to have almost duplicated code?

Comment: Sure, just extract that line into its own method (which will accept one parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
[:origin, :destination].each do |key|
  ride.waypoints.new(params[key].permit(:zip, :street, :number, :district, :city, :state)) if params[key]
end
```